# Is it dangerous to call a function and pass it a restrict-qualified pointer?

Tags: c++, restrict-qualifier

Consider these two functions:

```
void foo(char * __restrict localPtr)
{
    // some work with localPtr
}

void bar(char * __restrict ptr)
{
    // some work with ptr
    foo(_ptr);
    // some other work with ptr
}
```

As `ptr` has been declared `__restrict` in `bar`, is calling `foo()` dangerous? By dangerous, I mean that the memory zone pointed by `localPtr` overlaps `ptr`'s one. What are the guidelines about that?

Comment: Isn' `restrict` only useful for *multiple* pointer arguments or am I misremembering that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `restrict` qualifier means that the only way for the called function to access the memory passed as `localPtr` in `foo` is via that pointer; there are no aliases to that memory.  This might enable the optimizer to produce better code because it doesn't have to worry about another pointer also changing the data.

In this context, and in most others, the `restrict` qualifier places an onus on you, the programmer making the calls, to ensure that you are honouring the 'no aliases' requirement.

There is no visible danger from the code above.

Note that most usually you have multiple pointers in the argument list when `restrict` is used.  From the C standard, compare:

```
void *memcpy(void *restrict s1, const void *restrict s2, size_t n);
void *memmove(void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

The first (`memcpy()`) says that the chunks of memory `[s1 .. s1+n-1]` and `[s2 .. s2+n-1]` must not overlap; you will get undefined behaviour if they do in fact overlap.  The second (`memmove()`) does not impose that requirement.

---

> But isn’t the call to `foo()` creating another pointer that is changing the data?

Yes, No, Sort Of ... but mostly No.

The pointer in `foo()` is certainly passed to `bar()`, but while `bar()` is running, the only way `bar()` can get at the memory is through the pointer it was passed.  Thus `bar()` is able to be compiled on the assumption that it has no alias for the memory it is working with.

When the compiler is processing `foo()`, it knows (ensures) that there is a sequence point after the arguments to `bar()` are evaluated and before the function is called, and another when the function returns. It knows that the data might have been modified by `bar()` since it was not passed a `const char *`.  Therefore, it will generate the code to account for these possibilities.  However, the compiler also knows that the only way that `foo()` can access the memory addressed by `localPtr` is via `localPtr` (that's what the `restrict` says), and it can proceed based on that assumption.

So, there is a second copy of the pointer while `bar()` is being called, but it is not in violation of the rules of `restrict` in any way.

Comment: But isn’t the call to `foo` creating another pointer that is changing the data?

Comment: OK. What I was afraid of was the following scenario: At the beginning of `foo()`, the contents of `*ptr` is stored in a register. Then `bar()` is called and it modifies `*ptr`. When `bar()` returns, `foo()` uses the register instead of fetching `*ptr` again because `foo()` is sure that only `ptr` can modify the zone.

Comment: That sequence could happen; the compiler must make sure it doesn't affect its operation.  The `restrict` doesn't really affect this.  If the compiler used the register value after the function call, the compiler is mis-optimizing (aka 'compiler bug').  If  `bar()` was defined as `void bar(const char * restrict data)`, then the optimization would be legitimate, but `bar()` would have had to break the promise of the `const char *` to affect things.  But by casting away `const` and then changing the data that it points at, the modified `bar()` is invoking undefined behaviour; anything goes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Casting away `const` is only UB if the identified object is actually `const` qualified.  Achieving maximum optimizations based upon `const` would require having several different flavors of the keyword that make different promises, with the form defined by the Standard being the loosest (making "const"ness of pointers a syntactic rather than semantic feature).  Other forms would be a variation of "const" pointer that recipients would promise never to write directly or cause to be written, and a variation that would promise that data which was observed more than once...

Comment: ...would appear identically every time it was observed.  Such things would allow very useful optimizations, but the Standard doesn't recognize any such concepts.

Comment: `foo` and `bar` seem swapped in this explanation? `bar` calls `foo` in the question, but this seems to assume `foo` calls `bar`